# SQL JOIN and COUNT COMMANDS

Tags: sql, join, count

I have two different tables, we will call `table 1` and `table 2`. Within `table 1`, I have a column known as `featureid` which is a numerical value that corresponds to a numerical value in `table 2` known as the `termid`. Also, within this table 2, each of the different `termid` corresponds to a plain text description of that termid.

What I am attempting to do is join the `featureid` in `table 1` to the `termid` in `table 2`, but have the output be a two column display of the plain text description and occurrence of each within table 1.

I know I need to use the `JOIN` and `COUNT` syntax within SQL, but not sure how to correctly write the command.

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think it's time you show CREATE TABLE statements, sample data and expected output. It would be great, if you prepared an SQL fiddle in sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think I have figured it out... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually only need one column in the `GROUP BY`.  It's also good practice to specify which values are coming from which table, like so:

```
SELECT 
    table2.textDesc, 
    COUNT(table1.featureid) AS OccurrenceCount
FROM 
    table1 
     INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON 
        table1.featureid = table2.termid
GROUP BY table2.textDesc
```

Comment: Ok, so I may have been a little unclear in the initial writeup, my question involves two tables: • feature: This is a 'normalized' schema, and all biological feature types are stored in this same table. The type_id column distinguishes them by giving each a different numerical type. • cvterm: Each of the numerical types from the feature table are given more user-friendly text-based names in this table. The cvterm_id field of this table can be directly linked to the type_id of the feature table.

Comment: Write an SQL query which lists the types of features in the feature table along with a count of each. Your output should look like a two column table (using column aliases 'feature type' and 'feature count') where the feature type is plain text and feature count is a numerical value:

Comment: @AHiggins- I think I have figured it out. You helped a bunch thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT textDesc, COUNT(featureid)
FROM table1, table2
WHERE featureid=termid
GROUP BY featureid, textDesc
```

Alternatively, you can use a different syntax (with the same end result) like so:

```
SELECT textDesc, COUNT(featureid)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON featureid=termid
GROUP BY featureid, textDesc
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `JOIN`?

Comment: @programmer43229 you can use a JOIN or just use the abreviated syntax ','. If you wish, you can replace the comma with 'JOIN' and replace 'WHERE' with 'ON'

Comment: @programmer43229 you CAN use the abbreviated syntax but it is a very bad habit to get into, mainly because you are mixing your join criteria into your WHERE clause and it can get confusing fast.  Amazingly some people cling on to this standard, usually the same ones who prefer the old "*=" syntax for OUTER JOINs.

Comment: @Richard Hansell, thanks. I've seen `*=` in older code but never knew what it meant so I would re-write the query.

Comment: @DanielAndré Ok, so I may have been a little unclear in the initial writeup, my question involves two tables: 
• feature: This is a 'normalized' schema, and all biological feature types are stored in this same table. The type_id column distinguishes them by giving each a different numerical type.
• cvterm: Each of the numerical types from the feature table are given more user-friendly text-based names in this table. The cvterm_id field of this table can be directly linked to the type_id of the feature table.

Comment: @DanielAndré Write an SQL query which lists the types of features in the feature table along with a count of each. Your output should look like a two column table (using column aliases 'feature type' and 'feature count') where the feature type is plain text and feature count is a numerical value: